# Hacer de [sqldeveloper] sinónimo de [oracle-sqldeveloper]

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Respondiendo a una pregunta, noté que existen las etiquetas [sqldeveloper](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqldeveloper) y [oracle-sqldeveloper](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-sqldeveloper)(ambas ya con varios años de antigüedad).

Mirando la wiki de etiqueta de ambos:

- [sqldeveloper]: *SQL Developer es un IDE (Integrated development environment - Entorno de desarrollo integrado) desarrollado por Oracle Corporation, para trabajar con bases de datos de Oracle.*
- [oracle-sqldeveloper]: *Oracle SQL Developer es una herramienta con soporte gráfico para el desarrollo de bases de datos. Principalmente Oracle Database*

A la fecha, las estadísticas de preguntas y observadores son:

- [sqldeveloper]: 66 preguntas, 2 observadores
- [oracle-sqldeveloper]: 260 preguntas, 15 observadores

Dado que esencialmente están hablando de lo mismo (de hecho, los enlaces de referencia en la información de etiqueta de cada uno apuntan al [mismo](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index-097090.html) [lugar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html)), sugiero lo siguiente:

**[sqldeveloper](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqldeveloper) → [oracle-sqldeveloper](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-sqldeveloper)**

Answer (score 0):

ya se realizo el merge y ahora: [sqldeveloper](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqldeveloper) sera un sinonimo de la original: [oracle-sqldeveloper](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-sqldeveloper)

***Información:***

> Oracle SQL Developer es una herramienta con soporte gráfico para el
> desarrollo de bases de datos. Principalmente Oracle Database

***Más Información:***

> [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) es una herramienta propietaria de Oracle
> Corporation gratuita con soporte gráfico para el desarrollo de bases
> de datos. Con SQL Developer,
>
> se puede navegar por los objetos de base de datos, ejecutar sentencias
> SQL y scripts SQL, editar y depurar declaraciones PL/SQL. También
> puedes ejecutar cualquier número de reports suministrados, así como
> crear y guardar tus propios. SQL Developer mejora la productividad y
> simplifica las tareas de desarrollo de base de datos.

Referencia: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/oracle-sqldeveloper/info